# Regarding video upload using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just a small requirement. I am using Paperclip to upload the video. I am using Rails 3.2.6 version. I have followed the same process which we used for a normal image upload. It is saving my videos to the path which I have mentioned in the model.rb file. But the video is not showing up in the show.erb. If a put the same URL in a new tab, I am able to load my video. But not in the same page. I don't know where I have gone wrong.

In my model.rb file,

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price,:video

  has_attached_file :video,
                :url => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/:basename.:extension",
                :path => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 

end
```

In my show.html.erb,

```
video_tag @product.video.url
```

Comment: What's the output of just @product.video.url and how you tried with just link_to?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [video_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_path) instead of video_tag.

---

Also here's how I do this myself on my own site:

1 - Create a partial called `_video.html.erb` (I actually use slim, but erb will do if you prefer it) and put it in a folder like views/shared or something, and put the following code in it:

```
<iframe width="490" height="275" src="<%= url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

2 Add the following method to `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # this method will embed the code from the partial
  def show_video(url)
    render :partial => 'shared/video', :locals => { :url => url }
  end 
end
```

3 - now just call this in your views with:

```
<%= show_video @product.video.url   %>
```

This works ok for me

Comment: It is not working for me..And what exactly the :url option meant for?? i think i haven't mentioned :url correctly..and can we upload the video from anywhere of my system?? or from the path which i have mentioned in :url option?

Comment: First of all, tell me few things : #1. Do you have `video_file_name`, `video_content_type`, `video_file_size` columns in product table.? They are mandatory. #2. Secondly, I think your `:video` attribute in your model is conflicting with paperclip `has_attached_file :video`. Please change any one of them. #3. What is the output of `@product.video.url`

Comment: Ya..I will give a detail description about what i have done till now...Previously i have Products scaffold with basic fields like name and price...later on i have added video column to it...using     ----rails generate paperclip products video--- then i have run rake db:migrate....It has created 4 columns in my DB(video_file_name, video_content_type,video_file_size and video_updated_at) .Then i have added the above code to my model.rb

Comment: the output of                                                         @product.video.url is "/home/mercury/Desktop/aptana/simple_cms/app/assets/images/kat.flv?1353306158 "  ...The path upto kat.flv is correct because it is the path where the video is located.But why am getting 1353306158 ??

Comment: The path is correct. the value at the end is just a hash that rails append for caching and all. Neways, i think the matter here is to show it correctly. Did you follow my answer.?

Comment: The output of __show_video @product.video.url__ is                    undefined method `show_video' for #<#<Class:0xb2bf6e9c>:0xb29f3bb8>

Comment: `show_video` is a helper. If it is in `application_helper.rb`, then it is accessible from any view. You have to put `<%= show_video @product.video.url   %>` in your `show.html.erb`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19747/discussion-between-harshitha-and-ramandeep-singh)

Comment: If you guys figured out the solution, can you please update the answer